# SELECT count(*) with where produces weird values

Tags: mysql, laravel

It seems when I am trying to make a query to get the users transaction sum, it does not return the proper value until I remove the filter on code, what is even more interesting is the filter on the bar code following works perfectly fine, it seems maybe there is an inconsistency between both the subqueries in the WHERE clause?

Explanation:

With the below query, when I remove the and code != "foo" AND code !="foobar" from the query, it returns the correct value, but I also tried changing it to code = "foo" or code = "foobar" to check if any of the results had these codes, and it returns null when I do this.

```
SELECT SUM(t.amount)
FROM transactions t
WHERE `t`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    AND `t`.`user_id` = 80
    AND `t`.`user_id` IS NOT NULL
    AND `manually_deleted_at` IS NULL
    AND
            (SELECT count(*)
             FROM `transaction_subcategories` s
             WHERE `t`.`transaction_subcategory_id` = `s`.`id`
                     AND `code` != "foo"
                     AND `code` != "foobar"
                     AND
                             (SELECT count(*)
                              FROM `transaction_categories` c
                              INNER JOIN `transaction_categories_transaction_subcategories` sc ON `c`.`id` = `sc`.`transaction_category_id`
                              WHERE `sc`.`transaction_subcategory_id` = `s`.`id`
                                      AND `code` = "bar") >= 1) >= 1
    AND `posted_date` BETWEEN "2016-04-01 00:00:00.000000" AND "2017-03-31 23:59:59.000000"
    AND `parent_id` = 0;
```

While I do realize this is a mysql query issue, the laravel ORM code is a bit cleaner:

```
    $income_transactions = \Auth::user ()->transactions ()
    ->notManuallyDeleted()
    ->whereHas('transactionSubcategory', function ($query) {
        $query
        ->where('code', '!=', 'foo')
        ->where('code', '!=', 'foobar')
        ->whereHas('transactionCategories', function ($query2){
            $query2->where('code', '=', 'bar');
        });
    })
    ->whereBetween ( 'posted_date', [$from,$to])
    ->where('parent_id', '=', 0)
    ->get ();
```

**Update**
Not sure if this helps, but I did a query to see which subcategories it is returning with the WHERE clause and it returns only ones where the code is NULL 
mysql> SELECT * FROM transaction_subcategories WHERE id in ('1125', '630', '1395') AND code is null;

```
+------+-----------------------------------+------+---------+
| id   | name                              | code | user_id |
+------+-----------------------------------+------+---------+
|  630 | foo                               | NULL |      80 |
| 1125 | foo                               | NULL |      80 |
| 1395 | foo                               | NULL |      80 |
+------+-----------------------------------+------+---------+
```

**Update 2** Turns out it is the WHERE doing it, it seems that NULL values won't be compared against a string, in other words if I do a WHERE on a column that has nulls, the null value rows will disappear

**Answer** Turns out adding `OR code is null` in a group in the WHERE clause was all I needed. Closed :)

Comment: I hope this is the daftest naming policy we encounter today.

Comment: Looks good to me, thanks!

Comment: @Strawberry, the naming convention is mostly autogenerated from laravel :)

Comment: This is the first time in my life I have seen a WHERE condition cause a random bug in the output, for more insight, when the WHERE clause is there, no matter what I put as the code value, it gets 111631.08999999998 however when I remove the code clause it gets 115054.59. It isn't actually hitting anything with the filter but it breaks the calculation, which makes no sense to me, and when I reverse the condition to = it just returns NULL, even if there are transactions with that code in the subquery

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If not can you post the schema of transactions transaction_subcategories transaction_categories and transaction_categories_transaction_subcategories